# Making Apps For Galaxy Gear

Tags: java, android, galaxy

Iv'e been working with Android developement and I just recently bought a galaxy gear and want to start making apps for it? Is there anyway I can do that? Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you develop for the Gear just like an android device using the android sdk.

you will want to setup an emulator with a screen size of 320x 320 with 512mb of ram.

It also appears that right now samsung is not accepting 3rd party submissions to the samsung store.